# Bound for this integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

[image]

Using the fact that 
$$\sqrt{(1+y^2)} - \sqrt{(1+x^2)} \geq \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}(y-x)$$
for each $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. We need to show that 
$$L(k)- L(h) \geq \int_a^b \frac{h'}{\sqrt{1+{h'}^2}} (k' - h') dx \geq \frac{1}{R} |D|.$$

Here I am not sure if I could use integration by parts to recover something like
$$- \int_a^b \left(\frac{h'}{\sqrt{1+{h'}^2}}\right)' (k - h) dx.$$
And try to figure out a $||\cdot||_{L^\infty}$
bound on the first term, then show that this bound is greater than $\frac{1}{R}.$

I also tried to use $h'(x) = \frac{-(x-a)}{\sqrt{R^2 - (x-a)^2} }$ and calculate it explicitly, but the calculation got really messy.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to mention that both $k,h$ are concave down. And I added the picture.

Comment: This is false, let $k: x\mapsto \sqrt{1-x^2},\; h: x\mapsto -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ be define on $[-1,1]$. This satisfies your conditions, but yet $L(k)-L(h)=0<{1\over 1}\cdot\pi$. If you demand differentiability up to the endpoints, you can shorten the domain and pull the two mirror image arcs together by a vertical shift.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that both $k,h$ are concave down. There is a picture for this problem.

Comment: $ h $ is an arc of a circle of radius $ R $, how about $ k $? Please, add your graph!

Comment: Ok, I uploaded the picture.

Comment: Try: imagine that we have two intersected circles $ c_1$ and $ c_2$ with radii $ R, R_1$ respectively.  So that $ h $ is a part (arc) of $ c_1$ and $ k $ is a part of $ c_2$, use the equations $ x^2+y^2=R^2$ and $x^2+y^2=R_1^2$ to represent $ h \& k$ or to find a useful relation ( try in this way)